# overlaying rollover images on top of each other using CSS

Tags: html, css, alignment

It seems simple but for some reason won't work. I need Image 2 to work as a rollover and be centered in the middle of the first one but on top of it. I have this so far:

```css
.image1 {
z-index: 1;
top: 10vh;
width: 100%;
position: static;
}

.image2 {
z-index: 3;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding; 4vh;
position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img class="image1" draggable="false" src="https://icdn2.digitaltrends.com/image/google-campus-hq-headquarters-home-offices-720x720.jpg?ver=1.jpg" alt="Alt Tag">

<img class="image2" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/images/2/28/Google_2015.svg/revision/latest?cb=20170804092955" onmouseover="this.src='https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/images/2/25/Google_2015_%28Black%29.svg/revision/latest?cb=20171130074159'" onmouseout="this.src='https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/images/2/28/Google_2015.svg/revision/latest?cb=20170804092955'">
</div>
```

Image one displays fine but image 2 displays below it or on top of the content that's below instead of on top of the image. I'd rather use CSS to do this than JavaScript but can't really find a way for either when it's a rollover?

Thanks in advance.

Edit;
like this:
[How It Should Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gT9g2.png)

Comment: I've added image URLs for the example. I just need the rollover to work overlayed on the center of the background image @banzay, thanks :)

Comment: it's not clear what you want ...

Comment: It is. I just need image2 to overlay on top of image1 in the center. @TemaniAfif

Comment: Line `padding; 4vh;` has a mistake. `...ng; 4` - must be `...ng: 4`

Comment: replace `position: static;` with `position: absolute;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will do:

```css
.parent {
  max-width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.image1 {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.image2 {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 65%;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .image2 {
    max-width: 600px;
  }
}

body {
  margin: 0; /* cancel default 8px margin on SO */
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* make elements include paddings in width/height */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img class="image1" draggable="false" src="https://icdn2.digitaltrends.com/image/google-campus-hq-headquarters-home-offices-720x720.jpg?ver=1.jpg" alt="Alt Tag">

  <img class="image2" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/images/2/28/Google_2015.svg/revision/latest?cb=20170804092955" onmouseover="this.src='https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/images/2/25/Google_2015_%28Black%29.svg/revision/latest?cb=20171130074159'"
    onmouseout="this.src='https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/images/2/28/Google_2015.svg/revision/latest?cb=20170804092955'">
</div>
```

The important part is `position:relative` on parent and `position:absolute` on second child, the rest are just some max-values to make sure they are resized on narrower screens and some centering (both vertical and horizontal) on parent.

A few more pointers:

- neither `draggable="false"` or `position:static` are needed, as they're default values. But they're not wrong.
- you also don't need `z-index` at all here, as any item is rendered above its preceding siblings, in case they overlap (except when one of them is positioned (has a set `position` value, other than `static`) and the other one is not, in which case the positioned one is on top.

Comment: Perfect, Thank You! @AndreiGheorghiu :)

Answer (score 1):

There looks like there are a few issues here.  I think this is what you are looking for.

For your div, give it a relative position.  Then, for each image, give them an absolute position.  At that point the images should sit ontop of each other and there positioning will be absolute to the div and not the body.

ex.

```
div {
  position: relative;
}

.img1 {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
}

.img2 {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: that's covering the rest of the content on the page @Xtw

Comment: I need them to both be inline with the rest of the website so that content can still go above and below. I also need the overlayed image to be in the center but that also doesn't work @Xtw

Comment: Yep, they should be.  I only wrote an example of the css.  What you need to make sure you do is the div containing the two images has to have a relative position.  i see you updated it with the image urls.  I can make you a quick fiddle.

Comment: Np, here's a fiddle if you ever need a reference.  https://jsfiddle.net/0gpcxs8p/15/

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="parent" style="background-image:url('https://icdn2.digitaltrends.com/image/google-campus-hq-headquarters-home-offices-720x720.jpg?ver=1.jpg');">
    <img class="image2" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/images/2/28/Google_2015.svg/revision/latest?cb=20170804092955" onmouseover="this.src='https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/images/2/25/Google_2015_%28Black%29.svg/revision/latest?cb=20171130074159'"
onmouseout="this.src='https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/images/2/28/Google_2015.svg/revision/latest?cb=20170804092955'">
</div>
```

Can you just add the picture as background for the div?